# Dynamically created worker daemon queues in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: laravel, queue, worker, lumen

I need to create multiple dedicated daemon worker queues per type of job on a per account basis.

For instance, suppose I have 1000 accounts that needs a dedicated listener for each of it's job types. Each job type needs it's own dedicated worker to process 50 instances in parallel. I don't want any account to block the workers from another account and I want all workers for an account to run asynchronously. I want all 50,000 workers humming along happily without blocking.

How could I dynamically spawn listeners in-code for each account?

Could I expect to have a heavy memory footprint from running 1000's of daemon listeners or are they lightweight?

Is a particular service such as Redis, Beanstalkd, etc better suited to such goals?

Planning to try this in Laravel or Lumen 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a linux VM with 2Gb of RAM & CPU Frequency of 3.3GHz (1 Core), and the stat result from `ps aux` command:

[image: Ps aux stats]

The Resident Set Size for one queue is at its lowest ~52 MB (50888 KiB) and highest ~70 MB (68752 KiB).

1000 Workers = 52,000 MB (**52 GB**) - 70,000 MB (**70 GB**)

The cpu usage seems rather insignificant.

Note: my php-fpm is currently on version 5.x. If you target php 7.x, more performance gains can be attained.

Comment: Very nice stats! How did you dynamically spawn each individual daemon listener through code? And do you know a way to reduce the overall memory footprint?

Comment: Using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to monitor and spawn the queue workers. As for the memory footprint, you'll have to dive into the booting process of the framework and offload a few modules. Also, you can set the memory limit by providing a --memory option when starting the listener, but by default it’s 128 megabytes. Either spawn multiple queue workers on one VM or multiple VMs through auto-scaling behind a load balancer.